# Intercambio de elementos en listas en python

Tags: python

```
def ordenar_listas():
    lista_nombres= ['evangelina','pia', 'julian', 'eduardo']
    padron =[102694, 102693,102695,102696]
    lista_nombres.sort()
    padron.sort()
    lista_paralela =[]

    for  elemento in lista_nombres:
          for elemento1 in padron:
               lista_paralela.append(elemento)
               lista_paralela.append(elemento1)
```

Tengo que ordenar dos lista e intercambiar los valores de ambas en una tercera,
quedaria asi :

```
lista_paralela =["eduardo",102693,"evangelina",102694....]
```

Pero no logro hacerlo.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿Por qué el primer y tercer elemento son 102693?

Comment: Supongo que quieres hacer algo como `sorted(zip(lista_nombres,padron))`

Comment: Si , pero no tengo que usar la  funcion zip.

Comment: Error de dedo @eyllanesc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veas a ver...

```
    lista_nombres= ['evangelina', 'pia', 'julian', 'eduardo']
    padron =[102694, 102693, 102695, 102696]
    lista_nombres.sort()
    padron.sort()
    lista_paralela =[]

    for i in range(0, len(lista_nombres)):
        lista_paralela.append(lista_nombres[i])
        lista_paralela.append(padron[i])
    print(lista_paralela)
```

['eduardo', 102693, 'evangelina', 102694, 'julian', 102695, 'pia', 102696]